# Windows PATH and Run command

Tags: windows-10, path, run-dialog

I have a folder called `C:\bin\` that I like to keep a lot of scripts and bat files in. One of those files is `cmder.bat`, which just opens cmder.exe in it's installation folder:

```
@echo off
start C:\Users\<Username>\cmder\cmder.lnk
```

`C:\bin` is the second item in my PATH variable.

I like to start cmder by hitting winkey + R and typing in `cmder`, and until recently it would open cmder for me.
For whatever reason, typing `cmder` into the Run dialog now opens cmder's installation folder under `C:\Users\<Username>\cmder` in Windows Explorer.

Also, if I type `cmder` from cmd or powershell, it opens the program correctly and not the folder. It's only the Run dialog that opens the folder.

I have other programs that I like to start this way, and those still work without opening any folders or anything.
I have even duplicated the setup on another Win 10 machine, and `cmder` in Run works as intended.

Does anyone know what changed or where I can look to get this back to the way it was?

Comment: Check to see if the executable is still in `c:\bin` or not and update your post whether it is or not. Other programs in `c:\bin` still working from command line indicates something changed about the `cmder` application. Perhaps the PATH has changed. Open up a command shell window and type the command `set` to get a list of your environment variables. Check the environment variable `Path`. The way `Path` finding works is that the paths in the semicolon delimited list are checked one by one until the application is found and the search stops. A `Path` order change might be the problem.

Comment: The `bat` file is still in `C:\bin`, and the PATH is correct. See above for another update.

Comment: Be sure the cmder.exe installation path is in the PATH env variable.Do from command prompt `ECHO %PATH%` and paste back the result output.

Comment: Add to your posting the contents of the `cmder.bat` file so that we can see what it is doing. The behavior sounds like there is a command to open the folder containing the target like doing a right click to open a shortcut link then doing a find target. Were there any changes to the `cmder.bat` file?

Comment: @Facebook it is the `bat` file in the bin folder, not the `exe`. This was working fine for the longest time. @RichardChambers Contents of `cmder.bat` added.

Comment: The run applet maintains an history of launched items, maybe you opened that folder from the run applet by mistake and now is the history taking precedence over the bat file, check if the folder appears in the dropdown menu before typing anything.

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez Yes, you're right, that one appears in the Run Dialog history. However, if I go to regedit > \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU, I don't see this one listed. Does Run search your home folder by default?

Comment: I don't know where entries are stored but if you want to delete that entry just select it in the list and press `Delete` (note this is only before you type anything, if you start typing the run dialog can autocomplete searching matching files).

Comment: `Delete` in the Run box isn't doing anything for me, sorry.